# I embed a Python interpreter in my C program. How do I evaluate my Python plugin coverage?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, coverage.py, test-coverage

I have a C program that embeds the Python interpreter and is partially written in Python. I have tests written in C and when they run, the Python code is being executed.

How do I measure my test coverage of the Python code in this setting?

Comment: Going the other way, measuring coverage for a C module in a Python program: https://emptysqua.re/blog/code-coverage-python-c-extensions/

Comment: Kudos to testing dedication!